# Switching website from http to https, lost Facebook share count

Tags: facebook, share

Since recently switching a website from http to https the News section on the website "which has a Facebook "Share" button" has lost all the counts for that URL.

I have tried the following:

1. Add og:url tag on the HEAD section of the website `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com" />`
2. Modifying the Facebook code to count http likes
3. Using the Facebook Developers sharing debugger - The client put the old URL it used to be before the switch and scraped the http version but there was no change to the share counter
4. Use 301 Redirect on web page for HTTP to HTTPS - anybody trying to go to a http URL is redirected to the new URL on https

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And the result of step #3 was …? And for #4 you implemented the necessary exception for the FB scraper?

Comment: You need to follow the procedure as outlined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1149655968420144

Comment: Many thanks, I have followed this procedure using the og:url using the old URL of http and not https is this correct?

Comment: Well, depends on whether that old HTTP still returns the OG meta data to the FB scraper.

Comment: #CBroe - many thanks for your help, we have gone back into the Facebook scraper and this has now picked up the new changes, cheers

Comment: @Craig I have the same issue but I have not been able to solve it. I have the canonical tag and og:url tag pointing to http and when I scrape the page it keeps returning the https urls. I see you have a 301 redirect in place also. I'm thinking that might be the reason why scraper keeps returning the https url. You did not have this issue?